# Force Edge to run only in iGPU on my laptop

Tags: graphics-card, windows-11, microsoft-edge, asus-laptop, battery-life

As the title says, I'm trying to restrict Microsoft Edge to run using only the Intel iGPU to save energy on battery and avoid unnecessary stress and high temperatures when plugged. I tried to do it through Windows 11 own settings (Settings apps > Display > Graphics).

Graphics settings Microsoft Edge (msedge.exe):

[image: (Graphics settings msedge)]

But, despite setting Microsoft Edge to Power Saving mode, it keeps running in my dGPU (as GeForce Experience and Armoury Crate reports).

GeForce Experience GPU Activity report:

[image: (GeForce Experience GPU Activity report)]

I'm having a tough time any accessible solution to this problem, maybe someone here managed to make this work?

My laptop is an Asus ROG Zephyrus M16 - i7/RTX3070

Comment: @John Actually it should be possible -and- the default for any web browser. PS - This isn't Reddit therefore there are no "subreddits". Please [edit] out that nonsense.

Comment: Try to disable hardware acceleration in the browser's settings.